# Flutter unity communication issue

Tags: c++, flutter, unity-game-engine, dart, arcore

I an new to unity and I have a scene that I must integrate into a flutter app as part of my job (An AR scene). I connected the scene successfully but the problem is that the communication between flutter and unity is not working . The `onUnitySceneLoaded` & the `onUnityMessage` are not working. Only the `onUnityCreated` is working and displaying prints. To my understanding I need to add some code to the unity scene to make its messages be recognized by flutter and the [Flutter unity package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) . So lets ignore this for know and investigate why is `onUnitySceneLoaded` not working. Shouldn't it work out of the box automatically. This function will work directly after the unity scene appears right ?
Here is my entire flutter code for the unity screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_unity_widget/flutter_unity_widget.dart';

class UnityMainScene extends StatefulWidget {
  UnityMainScene({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _UnityMainSceneState createState() => _UnityMainSceneState();
}

class _UnityMainSceneState extends State<UnityMainScene> {
  UnityWidgetController _unityWidgetController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment(0.8, 0.0),
              colors: [
                const Color.fromRGBO(109, 180, 194, 1),
                const Color.fromRGBO(83, 116, 234, 1),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  clipBehavior: Clip.antiAlias,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                        bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                        bottomRight: Radius.circular(50)),
                  ),
                  child: UnityWidget(
                    onUnityCreated: _onUnityCreated,
                    isARScene: true,
                    onUnityMessage: onUnityMessage,
                    onUnitySceneLoaded: onUnitySceneLoaded,
                    fullscreen: false,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    GestureDetector(
                      child: Image.asset('assets/images/wallet.png'),
                      onTap: () => Navigator.pop(context),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  void onUnityMessage(message) {
    print('unity message recieved by anass');
    print('Received message from unity: ${message.toString()}');
  }

  void onUnitySceneLoaded(SceneLoaded scene) {
    print('unity scene loaded by anass');
    print('Received scene loaded from unity: ${scene.name}');
    print('Received scene loaded from unity buildIndex: ${scene.buildIndex}');
  }

  // Callback that connects the created controller to the unity controller
  void _onUnityCreated(controller) {
    print('unity scene created by anass');
    this._unityWidgetController = controller;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Okay, so the function `onUnityCreated` is called, right?

You then assign the controller to an instance variable such that you can call that variable to send messages to the Unity part of the application. I do now know why you would need the `onSceneLoaded` as your question is about communication so I will not handle that for now.

**PART 1**
In order to send a message from Flutter to Unity, you would need to call

```
_unityWidgetController.postMessage(
    'SomeGameObjectName', 'FunctionName', 'Hello world!');
```

In your Flutter project on the instance variable. Then, in your Unity project, you need to have a `GameObject` with a certain name (e.g. `SomeGameObjectName`) and that `GameObject` must have a script attached with a function with the following signature

```
public void FunctionName(string args)
{
    Debug.Log($"Received flutter message: {args}");
    // DO STUFF (WITH ARGS)
}
```

This will print

> Hello world!

in your console, coming from Unity.

**PART 2**
Now, for communication from Unity To Flutter.

At the place where you would want to call a message to Flutter, add the `UnityMessageManager` component to your GameObject. This class is provided with the plugin if you followed [the steps](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_unity_widget) correctly

[image]

Then, put the following piece of code in your Unity C# script of the `GameObject` with the `UnityMessageManager` attached.

```
private UnityMessageManager Manager
{
    get { return GetComponent<UnityMessageManager>(); }
}

Manager.SendMessageToFlutter(message);
```

This will send a message to flutter and will be called inside your `onUnityMessage(message)` function.

Comment: I am getting this issue after above implementation.     AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='onUnityMessage' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;

Comment: From Unity to Flutter I suppose? This is either a wrong name (check capitalization) or bad function signature. Try limiting the parameters you send from Unity to Flutter to strings.

Answer (score 0):

communication from Unity To Flutter.
Just add Component *UnityMessageManager* from inspector

And you have component *Default Observer Event Handler*  by default.
Just add Image Target or Something else to *OnTargetFound()* and send the string to Flutter

Like the gif below

[image]